# How do I edit multiple class names?

Tags: javascript, html, class, loops, iteration

My html:

```
<a id="Year2016">2016</a>

<div class="Month">
        <a class="Jan">Jan</a>
        <a class="Feb">Feb</a>
        <a class="Mar">Mar</a>
        <a class="Apr">Apr</a>
        <a class="May">May</a>
        <a class="Jun">Jun</a>
        <a class="Jul">Jul</a>
        <a class="Aug">Aug</a>
        <a class="Sep">Sep</a>
        <a class="Oct">Oct</a>
        <a class="Nov">Nov</a>
        <a class="Dec">Dec</a>
</div>
```

My js:

```
$("#Year2016").click(function() {
    $('.Month a').attr("class", $('.Month a').attr('class') + "2016");
});
```

my code is changing all the classes to "Jan2016" when I'm trying to just add "2016" to the end of each individual class. I've been messing around with the $.each() function to fix this, but I can't wrap my mind about how to use it correctly.

Update: Someone deleted this answer, but this works as well;

```
$("#Year2016").click(function() {
    $('.Month a').each(function(){ 
        $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr('class') + "2016");
    });
});
```

Comment: @ShifarShifz Haha... give me 1 sec I"ll show you how

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something fundamentally wrong, _why_ do you want to do this? What ever it is that you're doing, it sounds like there's an easier way.

Comment: @Nit Maybe... this is becoming more complicated than I imagined haha. I have 24 pdf files (2 years of calendars) that I thought would be cool to display month by month instead of just two 12 page pdf files.

Comment: But why do you need to create classes like that?

Comment: @Nit I'm trying to get the class name to correspond with the file name. My next function uses the class name to load the correct file

Comment: @melmar12 It sounds like you're approaching this all wrong. You just have two year's pdfs and want to make them available via links?

Comment: @Nit I'm displaying them in an <object> with the option to download them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`attr`'s function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to set the class for each element in the collection, eg:

```
$('.Month a').attr('class', function(idx, val) { 
    return val + '2016';
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbLsbomx/)

Note: if you have multiple classes, `2016` would be appended to the last class, eg:

```
<a class="Jan example"> --> <a class="Jan example2016">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to append the year to the end of the month. In that case

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Year2016").click(function() {
        $('.Month').children('a').each(function () {
        var newVal = this.text+" 2006";
        this.text = newVal;
        });
    });
});
```

Output:
`Jan 2006 Feb 2006 Mar 2006 Apr 2006 May 2006 Jun 2006 Jul 2006 Aug 2006 Sep 2006 Oct 2006 Nov 2006 Dec 2006`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick... let me know if you need anything else?

[Here is the **JSFiddle** Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x1quj7of/)

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addYear();">2016</button>
    <div id="year">
        <a class="Jan">Jan</a>
        <a class="Feb">Feb</a>
        <a class="Mar">Mar</a>
        <a class="Apr">Apr</a>
        <a class="May">May</a>
        <a class="Jun">Jun</a>
        <a class="Jul">Jul</a>
        <a class="Aug">Aug</a>
        <a class="Sep">Sep</a>
        <a class="Oct">Oct</a>
        <a class="Nov">Nov</a>
        <a class="Dec">Dec</a>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

//JS (index.js)

```
function addYear(){
    var year = document.getElementById("year");
    var months = year.children;
    for(var i=0; i < months.length; i++){
        var month = months[i].className;
        var addYear = month.concat("2016");
        months[i].setAttribute("class", addYear);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description your current approach seems rather convoluted. Personally I would approach this whole issue with a simple MVVM library. A neat example is [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/).
Keeping your data and display logic separately would allow you to avoid moving the information back and forth unnecessarily.

```js
var v = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data: {
        years: [2014, 2015],
        index: 0,
        months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    },
    methods: {
        select: function (i) {
            this.index = i;
        },
        foo: function () {
            var i = this.$$.select.selectedIndex;
            alert('get ' + this.months[i] + this.years[this.index]);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
a {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <p><a href="#" v-repeat="year: years" v-on="click: select($index)">{{year}}</a></p>
  <select class="links" v-el="select">
    <option v-repeat="month: months">{{month}} {{years[index]}}</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" v-on="click: foo()">Download</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out!